# Javascript. Mess with indexing when go through the found by getElementsByTagName nodes

Tags: javascript, indexing, getelementsbytagname

Help me please ! 
The task: using pure js , mix images (divs) and make them clickable: when clicked, it should remove the image if there is some background property set, and get the image back when it`s clicked and there is no background at all (kinda toggling, but remember: the task was using the pure js knowing nothing about any frameworks).
The problem is: there is 16 divs i get by getElementsByTagName (proven by alert :), and i can`t click the last div, because when i wrtie in the last for loop `z<div_arr.length` firebug throws an error: `div_arr[z]: undefined`. But when it is `z < div_arr.length - 1` it`s okay, but last div isn`t clickable.

here`s a piece of a code:

```
var div_arr=document.getElementById('wrapper').getElementsByTagName('div');
```

// sorting the array of images randomly

```
        document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function (){
                for(var j=0;j < div_arr.length; j++){
                var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * div_arr.length); // число от 0 до 15
                tmp=div_arr[randNum].className;
                div_arr[randNum].className=div_arr[j].className;
                div_arr[j].className=tmp;
            };
```

// eventhandling:

```
                for(var z=0; z< div_arr.length-1;z++){
                div_arr[z].onclick=function(){
                if(this.style.background==false)
                              this.style.background='none';
                else
                   this.style.background=div_arr[z].style.background;

            };
```